# In mat-table how would I show a dropzone above/below rows while dragging?

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-material-table

I have a mat-table and it's set up with drag and drop so the user can drag/drop rows to reposition them. What I'd like to do is display a drop zone between rows, so it's clear where the dropped row will go. I've been trying various things (like inserting a dummy row while they drag) but nothing has worked out so far.

Note: we are committed to using ng-drag-drop and are not using the CDK drag drop module, so solutions related to that aren't an option.

Has anyone done this? Any suggestions on a solid approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a drop zone between rows by using the `cdkDropList` directive from the Angular CDK library. You can apply the directive to the `tr` element that represents the rows in your table, and use the `cdkDropListData` directive to specify the data associated with each row.

Additionally, you can use the `cdkDropListConnectedTo` directive to specify which other drop lists the current drop list should be connected to. This will allow you to insert a drop zone between the rows as the user drags them.

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned, we are committed to use ng-drag-drop and are not using cdk drag drop...I'll update my question.